# Android Studio 4.1 - Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android-studio

Using Android Studio 4.1 sync fails with below error

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'AndroidBootcampAPK'.
>
> > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.fileProperty(Lorg/gradle/api/provider/Provider;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/RegularFileProperty;

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: downgrade your gradle version may help

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Gradle version was the problem. Thanks